# SQL: What is meaning of single column in join condition expression?

Tags: sql

What is meaning of single column in Join condition expession.
Eg.
In the following query, what table5.col_int_key and table2.pk
predicate do ? Is it simply colval !=0 ?

```
SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN COUNT(table1 .col_int) 
FROM   g table1 
       RIGHT JOIN e table2 
                  LEFT JOIN m table3 
                            LEFT JOIN a table5 
                              ON table5 .col_int_key 
                    ON table2 .col_int_key = table3 .col_int 
         ON table2 .pk; 
/* TRANSFORM_OUTCOME_UNORDERED_MATCH */;
```

Comment: In the given query, what table5.col_int_key and table2.pk predicate do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you're using MySQL, the only database that evaluates single columns as booleans.  So you are correct that it's equivalent to `colval != 0`, which is true if`colval` isn't `null` or `0`.

A primary key typically isn't `null` or `0`, so you can probably replace the `right join` with a `cross join`.

Comment: Oh ya.. it is mysql db, Thanks for answer.